# How to create such a beautiful titlepage

Tags: titles

I am trying to create such a beautiful titlepage with orange color, name andlogo of my university and "Mémoire de Master" for my master memoir in the place of "Thèse de doctorat". I am getting this Pdf from [Overleaf templates](https://fr.overleaf.com/latex/templates/template-paris-saclay-university-phd-thesis-2020/xqjtqtwcmztc).
Any help is really appreciated !!
[image]

Comment: Welcome :) // Did you "View Source" in your link?

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! It canbe done with the `eso-pic` package.

Comment: I did ! but I don't know how to create the violet part ("Bandeau_UPaS.pdf")

Comment: Thank you !  but I still a beginner in Latex and It seems to me too difficult to do !

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Some basic ideas for you:

> Edit: I forgot you said you wanna some orange color

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}
\definecolor{mycolor}{RGB}{255,148,44}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\newgeometry{left=7.5cm,bottom=2cm, top=7.5cm, right=1cm}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
remember picture,
overlay,
shift={(current page.south west)}] 
\fill [mycolor] (0,0) rectangle (7,\paperheight);
\foreach \loc in {0.3,0.7,1.2,1.8}
\draw [line width=2pt,white] (\loc,0) -- (\loc,\paperheight);
\node (title) [anchor=west,rotate=90,white] at (2.8,3) {\fontsize{35}{37}\selectfont\sffamily Mémoire de Master};
\node (name) [inner sep=0pt,anchor=west,mycolor,align=left] at (7.5,\paperheight-2.5cm) {{\fontsize{35}{37}\selectfont\sffamily Universite}\\[6pt]{\fontsize{20}{21}\selectfont\sffamily Name}};
\draw [fill=mycolor,draw=none] ([left=6pt]name.north east) circle (3pt) node (dot) {};
\draw [fill=mycolor,draw=none] ([above right=10pt]dot) circle (7pt);
\end{tikzpicture}
\bgroup\flushright
{\Huge\color{mycolor}\bfseries Title of Thesis}\\[2cm]
{\Large\bfseries Name of University}\\[1cm]
{\Large Name of Department}\\[1cm]
{\Large My Name}\\[1cm]
\egroup
\lipsum[1]
\clearpage

\restoregeometry
rest contents start here \dots
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much @Tom !! I really appreciate your help ! :)

Comment: You are welcome!

Answer (score 8):

The left side of this page is simply `\vrule \kern \vrule \kern...` with suitable parameters. I show the example using OpTeX (just for completness), where all main constructions is done directly by TeX primitives like `\hbox`, `\vbox`, `\vskip`, `\vrule`, `\hsize`, `\leftskip` etc. We need not to use TikZ macros. Doing such title pages is very comfortable using OpTeX:

```
\fontfam[Heros]
\margins/1 a4 (0,0,0,0)mm \nopagenumbers

\def\uniColor{\setrgbcolor{.384 0 .235}}

\hbox to\hsize{\uniColor
  \foreach 1 1.5 3 5 35 \do #1 {\vrule width#1mm \kern.8mm}
  \llap{\raise15mm\rotbox{90}
          {\White\typosize[33/]\bf Mémoire de Master}\kern22mm}%
  \hfil
  \vbox to\vsize{\Black \parindent=0pt \hsize=.67\hsize \leftskip=0pt plus1fill
     \kern 20mm
     \line{\picw=50mm \inspic UniLogo.pdf \hss} % Uni Logo from https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/3d/Logo_Université_Paris-Saclay.svg
     \vskip20mm                                 % and converted to pdf
     \typosize[25/35]\rm\uniColor 
         Titre de la thèse (sur plusieurs lignes si nécesaire, 4 voire 5)
     \vskip15mm
     \typosize[15/]\bf\Black Mémoire de Master l'Université Paris-Saclay
     \vskip25mm
     \typosize[15/18]\rm Next text text text\nl next text...
     \vskip35pt
     \typosize[15/]\bf\uniColor Prénom NOM
     \vfil
  }\kern12mm
}
\bye
```

I dont't know from what Uni you are, so I used directly the same Uni as in the given template. Note that you cannot copy the design (dots above e in the logo) from this Uni to the logo of your Uni (if it is different) but you must use exactly logo of your Uni. Then you can use orange color. But if your Uni is Paris-Saclay then the dark purple color must be unchanged because this is color selected as main color used in documents of this Uni.

[image: title]

Comment: Thank you so much but I have a problem to run your code, because I don't see the full peambule and the begin document ...

Comment: @BRH You see full document. This document is not LaTeX document but OpTeX document, so we don't need any more preamble here, no \begin{document} etc.. LaTeX, OpTeX and ConTeXt are formats  based on TeX with different syntax. OpTeX keeps the the plain TeX and primitive TeX philosophy most. And I show here that this title page can be created using these TeX primitive commands very straightforward.

Comment: Emm, Ok, but please I still dont know how to compile this code @wipet !

Comment: @BRH `optex document`